# How to edit inner array inside another array in php?

Tags: php

I have an array coming as below which is dynamic. Now I want to edit a specific array for  "BHD0000000002". I am getting the following array through ajax request. However I cannot edit the inner array element. For example, I am trying to edit the inner array value for the key "BHD0000000002" but unable to fix the issues. Can anyone help sir/madam?

> This is the original array:

```
$budget_detail_array=Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000001] => 10000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000002] => 12212121
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000003] => 212121
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000004] => 212121
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000005] => 212121
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000006] => 2121
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000007] => 2121
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000008] => 21221
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000009] => 2112212
        )

)
```

`I want to edit the above array as` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000001] => 10000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000002] => 5000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000003] => 212121
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000004] => 212121
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000005] => 212121
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000006] => 2121
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000007] => 2121
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000008] => 21221
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [BHD0000000009] => 2112212
        )

)
```

So far I have tried with the following code but it is not working. Anyone can help?

```
foreach($budget_detail_array as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $keyval=>$val){
        if($keyval=='BHD0000000002'){
            $val=5000;
        }
    }
    /*if($value[$budget_id]){
        $value[$budget_id]=100;
    }else{
        $value[$budget_id]=700;
    }*/
}
print_r($budget_detail_array);exit;
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What hve you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to modify an associative array value you can do this:

```
$budget_detail_array[1]['BHD0000000002'] = 5000;
```

And then check the result again

```
print_r($budget_detail_array);
```